# Trigger to insert into a table a "SELECT SUM" from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have these 2 tables:

[image: .]

The data in the table a AUX has duplicated dates, and the table a, must have the dates with no duplicates, BUT adding the total of the duplicated dates.

ej. 05/01/2017 = 123 + 123 + 123.

I'm thinks that a trigger should do the job when the data in the table a aux has new data.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[Table_a_aux] 
After Insert
AS
BEGIN

Declare @dDate as Date;
Declare @iTotal as int;

Select 
    @dDate = i.[date],
    @iTotal = i.total
From inserted i;


IF EXISTS (Select [date] from Table_a where [date] = @dDate) 
BEGIN
Update Table_a 
    SET total = total + @iTotal
WHERE
    [date] = @dDate
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table_a ([date],total) Values (@dDate,@iTotal)
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already did that, but if i want to edit a total from Table_a_aux, y must edit the 2, 3 or n duplicated dates.

Comment: Any changes in the table will change the data in the view as per the grouping

Comment: All the best :)

Comment: yes, of course, but i want the data in the view copy in a table, because the table_a_aux is just for referencie, the data in table_a is the official data.
If a data change in table_a_aux for example in 10 duplicates dates, i have to change those 10 dats, but in a Table_a just one.

Comment: Hi @gokufast i have updated my answer as per your requirement. please let us know in case of any clarification.

Comment: WOW, it works perfect, thanks Rahul.
It will help me alot.