# Database trigger How to insert sum of values, from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

***I think best way is Triggers? Any idea?***

I should insert sum of `payment_amount` seperately for each username from table **Payments**, to `total_money` table **total_balance** It should be inserted automaticly every time when new velues inserted to table **Payments**

***For example:*** User "John" filled his account 2 time 100$ and 50$, Total in his account 150$

***Example in tables:***

**Table: Payments**

```
 ID      username     payment_amount    Status  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |     100     | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  John       |     50      | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   3   |  Alex       |     100     | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**Table: total_balance**

```
 ID      username      total_money      
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  John       |     150     | 
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   2   |  Alex       |     100     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Usually keeping redundant is not a good idea. Let `total_balance` be a view that queries the sum instead.

Comment: @stickybit could you explain more detailed?

Comment: I wrote you an answer with more details.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not to keep redundant data. That is likely a recipe for desaster when inconsistencies occur. I suggest you use a view, that gives you the sums.

```
DROP TABLE total_balance;

CREATE VIEW total_balance
AS
SELECT p.username,
       sum(p.payment_amount) total_money
       FROM payments p
       GROUP BY p.username;
```

Or, if you only want to sum completed payments:

```
DROP TABLE total_balance;

CREATE VIEW total_balance
AS
SELECT p.username,
       sum(p.payment_amount) total_money
       FROM payments p
       WHERE p.status = 'Complete'
       GROUP BY p.username;
```

The figures in the view will always be accurate and reflect the current situation.

Comment: 1. ERROR:  Undefined 'p.username' at 'field list'  ?? What is "p"?
2. Using your view is it possible make substraction from total_balance? using queries?

Comment: @ShukurJank: 1.: `p` is just an alias. Is there a column named `username` in `payments`? 2.: No, you're no supposed to do that. Change the balance by adding a transaction in the payment table.

Comment: My problem similar with this, there SOLVED, Plz check and configure trigger with my table
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211374/trigger-to-insert-into-a-table-a-select-sum-from-another-table)

Comment: Plz correct [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211374/trigger-to-insert-into-a-table-a-select-sum-from-another-table) this answered code with with my table, I couldn't do myself, confused at all:(