# How to make this trigger workable with my tables?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I should insert sum of `payment_amount` seperately for each username from table **Payments**, to `total_money` table **total_balance** It should be inserted automaticly every time when new velues inserted to table **Payments**

***For example:*** User "John" filled his account 2 time 100$ and 50$, Total in his account 150$

***Example in tables:***

**Table: Payments**

```
 ID      username     payment_amount    Status  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |     100     | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  John       |     50      | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   3   |  Alex       |     100     | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**Table: total_balance**

```
 ID      username      total_money      
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  John       |     150     | 
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   2   |  Alex       |     100     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

***Here answered to my problem but I cant configure trigger as workable with my above tables***
[Here Solved 1-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211374/trigger-to-insert-into-a-table-a-select-sum-from-another-table)

Comment: The link provides a sqlserver answer - can you confirm you are looking for a MYSQL answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon  In above link we have same problem but different table names, and premetive datatypes, I should change with my table that trigger which answered

Comment: You didn't answer my comment, SQLSERVER and MYSQL triggers are not coded  the same way and are not interchangeable.

Comment: @P.Salmon  Yes I'm looking for MYSQL answer

Comment: @P.Salmon if you can create such triggers for my above problem could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on mysql triggers here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html. In this question the trigger code is trivial.

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key,name varchar(20),balance int);
create table t1(id int auto_increment primary key, tid int, amount int);
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on t1
for each row 
begin
    update t
        set balance = ifnull(balance,0) + new.amount
        where t.id = new.tid;
end $$

delimiter ;

insert into t (name) values ('john'),('paul');
insert into t1 (tid,amount) values
(1,10),(1,10),
(2,30);

select * from t1;
+----+------+--------+
| id | tid  | amount |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 |    1 |     10 |
|  2 |    1 |     10 |
|  3 |    2 |     30 |
+----+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
select * from t;

+----+------+---------+
| id | name | balance |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | john |      20 |
|  2 | paul |      30 |
+----+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the use of an isnull check on balance and the use of the NEW. columns (see manual)

Comment: Thanks bro, God bless you!!